# Push to different view controller by tapping a cell in Tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I am developing a application where i implemented a table view controller. Each row of the cell is of type accessory discloser indicator. Now i need to go to different table views by tapping different cells. 
I hope i should use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method to do this. But it acts good for navigating to only one view. How can i navigate for different  views by tapping different cells. Any help regarding this is really appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.row` property of `NSIndexPath`.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
          if(indexPath.row==0){
              //Push View Controller 1
          }
          else if(indexPath.row==2){
              //Push View Controller 2
          }
         //You can also use switch() instead of if
    }
```

if you want an event for tapping on accessory you can use following method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And dont forget to bind `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of the tableview.
For more info you can see document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate).
HTH.